# URL language code in ember.js routes

Tags: url, localization, ember.js, routes, url-routing

Is it possible to have global language code prefix in URL using ember.js? For example

```
/#/en/about
/#/de/about
```

in other words

```
/#/{language_code}/whatever/is/there/...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can nest your routes inside a `lang` resource like so.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('lang', { path: '/:lang_id' }, function() {
    this.route('about');
  });
});
```

You can then use the routes with `{{linkTo}}` for instance like,

```
{{#linkTo 'about' 'en'}}About (en){{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo 'about' 'de'}}About (de){{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: How would you access the `lang_id` to set `I18n.locale`?

Comment: `params.lang_id` in the `model` hook of the corresponding `LangRoute`.

Comment: @DarshanSawardekar So there is no need to add lang.about in first parametar of linkTo helper ?